# Target fragment within react const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants, gatsby, prismic.io

I am building my first react site, using gatsby with prismic.io as the CMS for my news section.

Within prismic I am using slices for quotes and featured images in each of the news stories and am looking to try and pull this data into my page, however I am unsure how to target the specific fragment names that I have created within the relevant `const` that has been set up for each.

**GraphQL Query**

```
export const query = graphql`
query ($slug:String){
prismicNewsStory (uid:{eq: $slug}) {
                data {
                body {
                    __typename
                    ... on PrismicNewsStoryBodyQuote {
                        primary {
                            quote {
                                text
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    ... on PrismicNewsStoryBodyFeaturedImage {
                        primary {
                            featured_image {
                                url
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
`
```

**Targetting consts**

```
const quote = props.data.prismicNewsStory.data.body[0].primary.quote.text
const featured_image = props.data.prismicNewsStory.data.body[1].primary.featured_image.url
```

As the slices are optional within prismic, I am encountering issues on some of the news stories when a `featured_image` is added before a `quote`, making them swap order within the `body`.

**Question**

Is there a way within each `const` to target a particular fragment or is there a better way for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking and learning a bit more learning with @paul-mcbride we came up with the following solution to target any `__typename`.

```
const body = props.data.prismicNewsStory.data.body.reduce((object, item) => ({
        ...object,
        [item.__typename]: item.primary
    }), {});
```

You can now use the targeted slice name.

```
<FeaturedImage src={body.PrismicNewsStoryBodyFeaturedImage.featured_image.url} />
```

or

`<QuoteText>{body.PrismicNewsStoryBodyQuote.quote.text}</QuoteText>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
//get the array
const body = props.data.prismicNewsStory.data.body;

const {feature_image : fi0, quote: q0} = body[0].primary;
// above line is equivalent to:
//  const fi0 = body[0].primary.feature_image;
//  const q0 = body[0].primary.quote;
// when order is reversed q0 will be undefined 

const {feature_image : fi = fi0, quote : q = q0} = body[1].primary;
// above line is equivalent to:
//  const fi = body[1].primary.feature_image || fi0;
//  const q = body[1].primary.quote || q0;
// when order is reversed fi0 will be assigned to fi

const feature_image = fi.url;
const quote = q.text
```

or use a reduce

```js
const reduceStory = (acc, item) => ({
  feature_image: acc.feature_image|| item.primary.feature_image,
  quote: acc.quote || item.primary.quote
})
const story = props.data.prismicNewsStory.data.body.reduce(reduceStory, {});

const feature_image = story.feature_image.url;
const quote = story.quote.text
```

>

Comment: Thanks @mke - first answer did work, however as the items are dynamically inputted, it didn't work when the items were in the opposite order. Reduce is what worked for me but I had to tweak it slightly so that I could target the `__typename`